# set custom attribute value according to product category in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to show custom attribute value according to category I have two options in attribute yes/no in this I have to show yes for one category and no for another category like there are two categories sunglasses and glasses I have to set yes for glasses and no for sunglasses in magento2

[image]

like this, if option yes should be selected by default in glasses category products and no for sunglasses and attribute is coming on product page

Comment: For frontend site?

Comment: yes in product page